# Mongodb: Combine $in and $nin

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-shell

In my collection `posts` I've documents like this

```
[{
  _id : ObjectId("post-object-id"),
  title : 'Post #1',
  category_id : ObjectId("category-object-id")

}]
```

I need to make some queries where I those a range of posts based on their category_id (can be multiple ids) but exclude some of them.

I've tried with the query (in shell):

```
db.posts.find({$and: [
  {_id: { $nin : ['ObjectId("post-object-id")']}}, 
  {category_id : { $in : ['ObjectId("category-object-id")']}}
]})
```

I returns 0 if count().

However, if I change the category_id attribute and remove the $in and just include **one** ID it work, like this:

```
db.posts.find({$and: [
  {_id: { $nin : ['ObjectId("58a1af81613119002d42ef06")']}}, 
  {category_id : ObjectId("58761634bfb31efd5ce6e88d")}
]})
```

but this solution only enables me to find by one category.

How would I got about combining $in and $nin with objectId's in the same manner as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, just remove single quotes around ObjectId

```
db.posts.find({$and: [
  {_id: { $nin : [ObjectId("post-object-id")]}}, 
  {category_id : { $in : [ObjectId("category-object-id")]}}
]})
```

You should not put single quotes around ObjectId, it make them strings

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I could swear that I already tried that, without the quotes around ObjectId, with no luck but apparently I haven't done it correct. Now it's working :-)