# Can we use $in and $nin together in a Mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, find

It seems that I can't find the answer to what appears to be a simple question.

Is the following query valid in Mongoose?

```
m.find({_id:{$in:A, $nin:B}}, ...);
```

Comment: Why should you not be able to? But I sense there is a real question behind this. Care to share? Or should we just submit our best guesses to what you really want to know for? How about showing the case where you think you want to use this but it does not work for you.

Comment: Well. I just couldn't find anyone doing this before. The closest example I found uses $and to join two {} clauses of _id: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225802/mongodb-combine-in-and-nin

Comment: Can you find `{ "field": { "$gt": 1, "$lt": 3 } }`? You should be able to because it's in the documentation. Same thing. You either don't have a query that works or you're just asking how to AND which is what two operators on the same key does. I'm still thinking you're actually trying to query like this and not getting the result you expect. Therefore "show the documents" and what you "expect to match" but are not. That's a question.

Comment: Alright. I guess you answered my question...

Comment: Tested and confirmed. You can totally combine $nin and $in.